# I am trying to get my Javascript to cooperate and open my hamburger icon with my links inside

Tags: javascript, html, hamburger-menu

Here is the code I am trying to get to cooperate with one another. I just need my Javascript to help in opening my hamburger icon menu. Currently, my hamburger icon works. It will create an "x" when clicked on, but it's just that my menu does not display when I click on the hamburger icon as it should.

```
* JAVASCRIPT *

export const navAnimation = function () {
    const hamburgerDiv = document.querySelector(".nav--hamburger");
    const hamburgerIcon = document.querySelector(".hamburger");
    const nav = document.querySelector(".nav--ul");
    const blur = document.querySelector(".blur");

    hamburgerDiv.addEventListener("click", () => {
        // nav.classList.toggle("hidden");
        hamburgerIcon.classList.toggle("hidden");
        cross.classList.toggle("hidden");
        nav.classList.toggle("move-in");
        nav.classList.toggle("move-out");
        // blur.classList.toggle("hidden");
        blur.classList.toggle("move-in");
        blur.classList.toggle("move-out");
    });
};

navAnimation();

// Hamburger Icon //
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#nav-icon1,#nav-icon2,#nav-icon3,#nav-icon4').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
    });
});


* HTML *

 <header class="header">
            <div class="blur move-out"></div>
            <div class="header--logo">
                <img src="images/Logo-2.png" alt="Site logo" class="logo"/>
            </div>
            <nav class="nav">
                <div class="nav--hamburger">
                    <div id="nav-icon1" class = "hamburger">
                        <span></span>
                        <span></span>
                        <span></span>
                      </div>
                </div>
                <ul class="nav--ul move-out">
                    <li class="nav--li--item">
                        <a class="nav--li--anchor" href="#home">
                            <span class="order"></span>HOME
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav--li--item">
                        <a class="nav--li--anchor" href="#about">
                            <span class="order"></span>ABOUT
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav--li--item">
                        <a class="nav--li--anchor" href="#services"
                            ><span class="order"></span>SERVICES
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav--li--item">
                        <a class="nav--li--anchor" href="booking">
                            <span class="order"></span>BOOKING
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav--li--item">
                        <a class="nav--li--anchor" href="#footer">
                            <span class="order"></span>CONTACT US
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>

* CSS *

<style> 
#nav-icon1 {
    width: 55px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px auto;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  #nav-icon1 span {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 3px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #551a00;
    opacity: 1;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
    transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  }
  #nav-icon1 span:nth-child(1) {
    top: 0px;
  }
  #nav-icon1 span:nth-child(2) {
    top: 10px;
  }
  #nav-icon1 span:nth-child(3) {
    top: 20px;
  }
  #nav-icon1.open span:nth-child(1) {
    top: 18px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(135deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(135deg);
    transform: rotate(135deg);
  }
  #nav-icon1.open span:nth-child(2) {
    opacity: 0;
    left: -60px;
  }
  #nav-icon1.open span:nth-child(3) {
    top: 18px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-135deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-135deg);
    transform: rotate(-135deg);
  }
.nav {
    font-family: "Bellefair", serif;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: var(--step-0);
    font-weight: 700;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: end;
    width: 80%;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .nav--ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 2rem;
    justify-content: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    align-items: start;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    padding-left: 2rem;
  }
  .nav--li--anchor {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  .nav--li--anchor:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .cross {
    position: absolute;
    top: 3%;
    right: 10%;
    transform: translate(-3%, -10%);
  }
  .blur {
    width: 80%;
    left: 20%;
    position: absolute;
    min-height: 118.3vh;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
    backdrop-filter: blur(15px);
    z-index: 2;
  }
  .hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  .move-in {
    animation: scale-in-hor-right 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94) both;
  }
  </style>
```

Comment: Do you have some CSS to complement that? At least for the classes involved.

Comment: Yes, I will add it now.

Comment: How many hamburger menus are on this page?  I can see it having trouble with more than one, and I think you have 4 - `$('#nav-icon1,#nav-icon2,#nav-icon3,#nav-icon4')`

Comment: There's only one use of cross no definition, that would be erroring out the rest of the following lines (right where you error). cross.classList.toggle("hidden"); // looks wrong it's not defined and will error.

Comment: @James I edited out the other icons. There is only one and it is "#nav-icon1."

Comment: Do you have a `move-out` class defined in CSS?

Comment: You've got two event listeners, that should respond to the same event, attached to two different elements:

1. .nav--hamburger
2. #nav-icon1

Fixing that should resolve your issue. Also, if you're using jQuery anyways, you can simplify your JS & CSS significantly.